# AudioConverterNew return OSStatus fmt

Tags: ios, audio-streaming, audio-converter

i'm trying to convert pcm audio got from AVAudioCapture to aac format. i use AudioConverterNew.But i always got an OSStatus 1718449215, i know it means kAudioFormatUnsupportedDataFormatError, but i don't know why, here's my code

```
 OSStatus status;
AudioStreamBasicDescription sourceASBD = *sourceFormat;
AudioStreamBasicDescription destASBD = {0};
destASBD.mSampleRate = sourceASBD.mSampleRate;
destASBD.mFormatID = kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC;
destASBD.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
UInt32 size = sizeof(destASBD);
status = AudioFormatGetProperty(kAudioFormatProperty_FormatInfo, 0, NULL, &size, &destASBD);
if (status != noErr) {
    NSLog(@"AudoFormatGetProperty kAudioFormatProperty_FormatInfo error:%d", status);
}

AudioClassDescription *description = [self
                                      getAudioClassDescriptionWithType:destASBD.mFormatID
                                      fromManufacturer:kAppleSoftwareAudioCodecManufacturer];
if (!description) {
    NSLog(@"get audio class Descriptin error");
    return false;
}
AudioConverterReset(_converter);
status = AudioConverterNewSpecific(&sourceASBD, &destASBD, 1, description, &_converter);

if (status != noErr) {
    NSLog(@"create audo converter error:%d", status);
    return false;
}
```

i got the sourceFormat from CMSampleBufferRef, anyone know what's the problem? the sourceASDB is

```
    mSampleRate = 44100
    mFormatID = 1819304813 linearpcm
    mFormatFlags = 12
    mBytesPerPacket = 2
    mFramesPerPacket = 1
    mBytesPerFrame = 2
    mChannelsPerFrame = 1
    mBitsPerChannel = 16
    mReserved = 0
```

Comment: Print out sourceASBD so we can take a look at it.

Comment: @Dave  i've add the sourceASBD, can u find anything?

Comment: Both your input and output ASBD look good. I ran the code and didn't get any errors.  I created an ExtAudioFileRef with a known good setting for aac and inspected it's output converter's format just for comparison and it was the same as yours. I got the getAudioClassDescriptionWithType  method from [FFmpeg-iOS-Encoder](https://github.com/chrisballinger/FFmpeg-iOS-Encoder/blob/master/FFmpegEncoder/AACEncoder.m)  Are you seeing the error in AudioConverterNewSpecific?

Comment: @Dave thank u. yes, the error is from AudioConverterNewSpecific,  i guess it has something to do with mFormatFlags, but the destASBD mFormatFlags is 0. i'll try again

Comment: Here is a working ASBD output for the converter.`mSampleRate 44100.000000
mFormatFlags 0
mFormatID 1633772320,aac 
mFramesPerPacket 1024
mBytesPerFrame 0
mChannelsPerFrame 1
mBitsPerChannel 0
mBytesPerPacket 0`

Comment: finally got it work ! But i don't know why maybe it's some xcoe weird bug